# GCC 6.3 throws a runtime error whenever the input is more than one number. What could be the possible reason?

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

This a preliminary attempt to solve the Bytelandian Gold Coin problem in CodeChef.

```
int main(void) {

    long long int n = -1;
    scanf("%lld", &n);
    while(n != -1){
        int b[n];
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)  b[i] = -1;
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)  printf("%d ",b[i]);
        printf("\n");
        n = -1;
        scanf("%d", &n);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your second `scanf` should use `"%lld"` just like the first one.

Comment: You have a second `scanf` with wrong format specifier.

Comment: You use '%lld' in one invocation of scanf and '%d' in the other.  Why are you calling scanf twice instead of `while( scanf ... == 1)`?

Comment: But there's not really much point in using `long long int` for `n`, as if the value of `n` is too large for `int` then you probably can't successfully allocate such a large array on the stack anyhow.